# Gmail forwarding verification code problem

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, verification

I'm trying to get someone to receive forwarded emails. I put in his email address. He received the message, but the account I'm sending from doesn't recognize his computer. So it wants to send the verification code to his phone, but it's saying his phone isn't registered with the account either. 
How can he get the code? How do I get him registered to receive forwarded emails?